# Hibernate lazy initialized collection with hint for Oracle DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hints

I have entity with lazy initialized collection:

```
SomeEntity someEntity = template.findByNamedQuery("queryName", entityId);
if (someEntity != null) {
    Hibernate.initialize(someEntity.getChildCollection());
}
```

Hibernate generate SQL:

```
SELECT 
  t.COL1 AS COL1_,
  t.COL2 AS COL2_,
  ...
  t.COLN AS COLN_
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t
WHERE t.COLX = :1
ORDER BY t.COL1 ASC;
```

There is index IDX_COLX on column COLX.

But for some unknown reason sometimes Oracle doesnt use this index and use full scan on table. I dont control DB, but I was told (by db admin) that solution to this is to pass hints for Oracle.

Something like this:

```
SELECT /*+ index(t IDX_COLX) */
  t.COL1 AS COL1_,
  t.COL2 AS COL2_,
  ...
  t.COLN AS COLN_
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t
WHERE t.COLX = :1
ORDER BY t.COL1 ASC;
```

Is there any simple way to force hibernate do attach this additional information to generated SQL query?
I dont want to rewrite whole application because of some Oracle bug or misconfiguration.

I use hibernate 3.3.2.

**EDIT:**

I tried solution given by StuPointerException and generated SQL looks like:

```
/*+ index(t IDX_COLX) */
SELECT
  t.COL1 AS COL1_,
  t.COL2 AS COL2_,
  ...
  t.COLN AS COLN_
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t
WHERE t.COLX = :1
ORDER BY t.COL1 ASC;
```

Tested that in Oracle SQL Developer and it looks like Oracle doesnt recognise this hint if placed before SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by enabling the property `use_sql_comments` on your `HibernateSessionFactory`:

```
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

You will then be able to do this:

```
String hql = "from SomeEntity e where e.COLX = :colx";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
        .setString("colx", "xyz")
        .setComment("+ index(t IDX_COLX)")
        .list();
```

It does mean that you have to take more control over the relationship in your code though, which is a bit of a pain.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Comment appeared indeed in generated SQL but unfortunately before SELECT statement and it didnt worked as it should.